# Add Assembly to the GAC and reference it from web.config

Tags: .net, dll, web-config, gac, .net-assembly

I Wrote a class Library (.Net Framework 2.0)

and I created an empty Web Application project

When I added the dll as reference to the Web Application project

everything works fine.

But when I added the dll to the GAC and write the following

lines to the web.config

```
<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
      <remove name="RedirectModule" />
      <add name="RedirectModule" type="RedirectModule.RedirectModule, RedirectModule, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=e81458cb6113cf4f"/>
    </modules>
```

sometimes it work and sometimes it doesn't work

How Can I solve this problem?

Thank You.

Comment: First thing to do is to determine the precise conditions when it fails and when it doesn't and then hone these down. When you have the smallest set of changes that make it go from working to non (or vice versa) then you can start looking at the why these influence the behaviour.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Add Class Library Assembly into web.config](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11710436/add-class-library-assembly-into-web-config)